# Match a sequence for detecting ingredient brand in regex

Tags: regex

By capturing the following pattern `; AAA-AAA` it is possible to detect an ingredient brand. It's a semi colon, a space (only one), three letter or number combination, a hyphen and three letter or number combination.

For example in this string: "Bakery: Desdemona (Desserts; A9B-APO) 7th Avenue" the ingredient is A9B-APO

A can be a number or a letter. I tried unsuccessfully to write a regex:

```
"^w(;s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])
```

Please, could you help me with this expression? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
;\s([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dEviLb/3).

**Details**

- `;` - a semi-colon
- `\s` - one whitespaces
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})` - Capturing group 1 (your value is here): three alphanumeric, `-` and three alphanumeric chars
- `\b` - a word boundary.

If the number of alphanumeric chars can be any, starting with one, you may use `;\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b`, where `{3}` is replaced with the `+` quantifier.

Comment: Hello @Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you very much for the help, I have edited the question because after the semi-color there should be only one whitespace. Should I change to `\s([a-zA-Z0-9...`?

Comment: @Manu Ok, remove `*` after `\s` to make it match a single whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and time @Wiktor Stribiżew, I see that this regex helps even to find vehicle plates in my country. It's really helpful, have a great day!